# How can I update my 3rd generation iPod touch from iOS 5.1.1 iOS 6.0

Tags: itunes, ipod, ios

My itunes keeps on telling me that my iOS 5.1.1 iPod touch is up to date when I click `Check for Update`:

- iTunes 11.0.2
- OS X 10.8.2
- iPod 3rd gen (MC008LL)

[image]
[image]

I recall that back in the day I used to get the prompt to update to 6.0.. and then I asked iTunes never to bother me about it again. But now I went to *iTunes->preferences->advanced->reset all dialog warnings.* that still doesn't work..

I also tried updating my software from within the iPod itself: *Settings->General->Software Update*, but I get the exact same message still.. Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't, iOS 6 requires at least an 4th generation iPod touch (as noted in the System Requirements (right hand side) of [Apples Update overview](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1578)).

Comment: oh.. I guess I was confusing the iphone 3gs with ipod touch 3gs.. my bad.. thanks!

Comment: There is no iPod touch 3gs, Apple calls it the "3rd generation iPod touch"